# Swagger-UI-Express not loading in Azure App Service: 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, azure, swagger-ui

I am able to pull up the Swagger-ui-express api-docs path locally without issue, but in attempting to load within a Node.js app hosted in an Azure App Service, it gives me a 404 not found when trying to hit the /api-docs/ endpoint. The rest of my node app loads in the Node Azure App Service. Of note, the 404 states the requested URL is: https://myapp:80/api-docs/

I have both URLs for my local instance and the Azure instance listed in the swaggerOptions/swaggerDefinition:

```
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "1.0.0",
      title: "My API",
      description: "My API Information",
      contact: {
        name: "My Name - my.name@email.com"
      },
      urls: [{"url":"http://localhost:3000", "description": "Development server"},{"url":"https://myapp.azurewebsites.net", "description": "Production server"}]
    }
  },
  // ['.routes/*.js']
  apis: ["server.js"]
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not at the Swagger layer. My package.json had the wrong main file listed, it worked locally but Azure was looking for index.js while I use server.js. Changing this to the correct value and redeploying resolved the issue.